# Check if radio butto's value already exists?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I want to make a query and check if data  exists already on my
is_availble table on calendar db tomake it unavailble .
I have 16 radio buttons.

I have now this code, but if I select whatever radio button of
those 16 radio buttons, first radio button disappears ?

```
$squery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM is_availble WHERE datetime=$v_datetime ");
echo"<div  class='box'>
<div class='boxbut'>";

if(mysql_fetch_array($squery))  {
echo" Booked ";
}
else{
echo" <input type='radio' name='datetime' value='". $row['day1']."   ".$row['time1']."'>
<d>". $row['day1'] ,"</d><br/><t>". $row['time1'] ."</t>";
}
echo"</div></div>";

//---------------------------------- choeckbox 2(bookable time 2)------------------------\\


echo"<div  class='box'>
<div class='boxbut'>";
if(mysql_fetch_array($squery))  {
    echo" Booked ";
}
else{
echo" <input type='radio' name='datetime' value='". $row['day1']."   ".$row['time2']."'>
<d>". $row['day1'] ,"</d><br/><t>". $row['time2'] ."</t>";
}
echo"</div></div>";
```

Regards

Comment: disappears or getting unchecked ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe is getting unchecked because you have same `name` for both types of radios.

Make the first radio set `datetime` and the second radio set `datetime2` and it should work.

Comment: actually it works. Problem is that it makes radio buttons uncelectable from the firs one. For example if I select radio button 10 it makes radio button one unavailble not 10.. And after refreshing page if I select another button(for example button 5) and submit the form, the secont button disappears, not button 5?